# How to automate login with a webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I'm trying to log into a (what I assume to be a) webapp and I get stuck trying to log into the website. Using WWW::Mechanize does work but in the responses from my post, content it print nothing more than a couple HTML Javascript:

```
<HTML>

<SCRIPT Language=JAVAScript>

 var msgTimerID;

 var strForceLogOff = "false";

 function WindowOnLoad(){

    if ("false" == "true" && "false" == "false") 
        MerlinSystemMsg("",64);

    if ("false"=="true") 
        msgTimerID = window.setInterval("MerlinSystemMsg(10095,64)", 300000,'javascript');

 }

 function MyShowModal(){

     showModalDialog("", window, strFeatures);}

 function clearMsgInterval(){

    window.clearInterval(msgTimerID);

 }

 function WindowOnUnLoad(){

     if(top.frames(0).document.getElementById("OPMODE").value =="LOGOFF"){

         strFeatures = "width=1,height=1,left=1000,top=1000,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes,resizable=1";

         window.open("ForceLogOff.aspx","forcelogout",strFeatures);

     }

 }

 window.onbeforeunload = WindowOnUnLoad;

 window.onload = WindowOnLoad;

</SCRIPT>

<FRAMESET  ROWS="57px, *" BORDER=0 FRAMEBORDER=0  STYLE="background-color=transparent"> 

<FRAME TITLE="Service Desk Express Navigator" SRC="Options_split.aspx?NavigatorName=1065" NORESIZE>  

</HTML>
```

There is also this Frame Title that has the src:

```
 FRAME TITLE="Service Desk Express Navigator" SRC="options_nailogo.aspx" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 NORESIZE scrolling=no
```

In general, how would I handle a response like this when the content is not the websites source, but mostly scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That content is the website source :)

[How WWW::Mechanize deals with FRAME SRC](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.68/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Efind_link%28_..._%29) as a link:

> Note that <FRAME SRC="..."> tags are parsed out of the the HTML and
>   treated as links so this method works with them.

You'll want to use `follow_link` on that link.

Comment: so could I just ignore the script that in the html and just follow the link from the SRC?

Comment: For this case, it looks like you can.  It's really a case-by-case sort of thing...some scripts you may need to evaluate.  For example, say you have a link, `<a href='javascript:someJSfunc(...)'>Link Text</a>`; you'd have to evaluate `someJSfunc` to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558704/using-python-to-automatically-login-to-a-website-with-a-javascript-form/6558887#6558887). Both [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) are good tools for automating interactions with sites that rely heavily on Javascript to display the user interface.

Comment: hmm isn't Selenium more for test, and if i used Phantom, is there Perl implementation?

Comment: Selenium is made for testing, but it can automate pretty much any user interaction, and it has a Perl client. It's a good tool if you don't mind running your interaction in an open browser. Phantom doesn't have a Perl implementation, but that doesn't really matter - you'd be writing your scripts in Javascript either way, which IMHO is by far the best way to interact with a Javascript-driven site.

Comment: yea, my mistake I forgot to say that I needed this project to run in the background. I will probably use Phantom later, depending on what I can do with Perl, thanks for the advice @nrabinowitz